# SurfaceView not working inside PopupWindow

Tags: android, surfaceview, popupwindow, surfaceholder

I gonna show a preview using a `PopupWindow` based on [AirView](http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk) feature of Samsung SPen

But the problem is that the `SurfaceView` is not created and non of the `SurfaceHolder.Callback` methods are called.

The surface region becomes transparent when the popup is displayed because the surface is not created at all.

`SurfaceView` **is not created** and is transparent:

[image]

`HoverPreview`:

```
public class HoverPreview extends LinearLayout implements View.OnHoverListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "HoverPreview";
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder = null;
    View mAnchorView = null;
    String videoPath;
    int position;
    private boolean IsMediaPlayerReady = false;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    Context context;

    public HoverPreview(Context context, String videoPath, int position) {
        super(context);
        this.videoPath = videoPath;
        this.position = position;
        setupLayout(context);
    }

    public HoverPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setupLayout(context);
    }

    public HoverPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setupLayout(context);
    }

    private void setupLayout(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_browser_hover, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "HoverSurface created");

        final Surface surface = surfaceHolder.getSurface();
        if (surface == null) return;
        if (!surface.isValid()) return;

        mHolder = surfaceHolder;

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mHolder);
        mAnchorView.setTag(mMediaPlayer);

        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i2) {
                mHolder.setFixedSize(i, i2);
            }
        });

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer preview is prepared");
                IsMediaPlayerReady = true;

                if (mMediaPlayer != null && IsMediaPlayerReady) {
                    if (position > 0)
                        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer is created");
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        Log.d(TAG, "HoverSurface changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "HoverSurface destroyed");
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            //thumbnailImageView.setTag(null);
        }
    }

    public void setAnchorView(View view) {
        mAnchorView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onHover(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        try {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_HOVER_ENTER");

                mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.media_browser_hoverSurfaceView);

                mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
                if (mHolder != null) {
                    mHolder.addCallback(this);
                }

            } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_HOVER_EXIT");
                if (mAnchorView.getTag() != null) {
                    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = (MediaPlayer) mAnchorView.getTag();
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    mMediaPlayer.release();
                    mAnchorView.setTag(null);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() + Utils.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code to show the preview:

```
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(context);
final HoverPreview hoverPreview = new HoverPreview(context, videoPath, 0);
hoverPreview.setAnchorView(thumbnailImageView);
thumbnailImageView.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onHover(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        hoverPreview.onHover(view, motionEvent);
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER) {
            popupWindow.setContentView(hoverPreview);
            popupWindow.setWidth(600);
            popupWindow.setHeight(400);
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(thumbnailImageView, ToolHoverPopup.Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 10, 10);
            Log.d(TAG, "Manual Hover Enter");
        } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Manual Hover Exit");
            if (popupWindow != null)
                popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
        return true;
});
```

Comment: Could you post the creator and `onHover` routines from `HoverPreview` please? Also, what class is `HoverPreview` built on?

Comment: @NeilTownsend, posted the full code and screenshot

Comment: Does `surfaceCreated` get called?

Comment: @NeilTownsend, I wish. Never. If it was, I didn't ask this question.

Comment: so is `onHover` (in `HoverPreview`) called?

Comment: Yes (Look at screenshot), the problem is not with the onHover. It's OK. The problem is that there's no way to inflate a SurfaceView inside a PopupWindow and get it's surfaceCreated method called

Comment: Have tried moving `inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_browser_hover, this, true);` to inside `onHover` so that the view is created when is will be visible?

Comment: @NeilTownsend, not worked. I think the problem is with the nature of PopupWindow. However I don't know how Samsung has managed to do the same on the Video app of GS4!

Comment: I will think more over night ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my complete **working** solution:

I borrowed some code from `ToolHoverPopup` class from SPen library, also I customized for this special popup so that nothing is created or inflated until the actual hovering is happened so that we don't consume resources for enabling such a preview in lists.

We need to have our preview attached to a `Window` so because of this we have to manage all the underlying job of positioning which is normally done by `PopupWindow`, so I completely removed the dependency on the `PopupWindow` and now my `HoverPreview` class is fully working and manages all the jobs, also it has the ability to determine the Hover Detection delay in milliseconds.

Screenshot (SurfaceView is created)

[image]

Usage: (Since the layout contains `SurfaceView` and is resource intensive, I manually trigger `onHover` event so that the real surface creation is performed only when the real hover is performed. Also by this, I don't create any object of `HoverPreview` before it's needed)

```
        thumbnailImageView.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onHover(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                HoverPreview hoverPreview;
                if (thumbnailImageView.getTag() == null) {
                    hoverPreview = new HoverPreview(context, getActivity().getWindow(), videoPath, 0);
                    hoverPreview.setHoverDetectTime(1000);
                    thumbnailImageView.setTag(hoverPreview);
                } else
                    hoverPreview = (HoverPreview) thumbnailImageView.getTag();

                hoverPreview.onHover(null, motionEvent);

                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT)
                    thumbnailImageView.setTag(null);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

`HoverPreview`:

```
public class HoverPreview extends LinearLayout implements View.OnHoverListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final int MSG_SHOW_POPUP = 1;

    private static final int MSG_DISMISS_POPUP = 2;

    private static final int HOVER_DETECT_TIME_MS = 300;

    private static final int POPUP_TIMEOUT_MS = 60 * 1000;

    protected int mHoverDetectTimeMS;

    private static final String TAG = "HoverPreview";
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder = null;
    String videoPath;
    int position;
    private boolean IsMediaPlayerReady = false;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    Context context;
    private HoverPopupHandler mHandler;
    Window window;

    public HoverPreview(Context context, Window window, String videoPath, int position) {
        super(context);
        this.mHoverDetectTimeMS = HOVER_DETECT_TIME_MS;
        this.videoPath = videoPath;
        this.position = position;
        this.window = window;
        setupLayout(context);
    }

    private void setupLayout(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_browser_hover, this);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.media_browser_hoverSurfaceView);
    }

    View rootView;

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "HoverSurface created");

        final Surface surface = surfaceHolder.getSurface();
        if (surface == null) return;
        if (!surface.isValid()) return;

        mHolder = surfaceHolder;

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mHolder);

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer preview is prepared");
                IsMediaPlayerReady = true;

                int videoWidth = mMediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
                int videoHeight = mMediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
                Point size = new Point();
                int screenHeight = 0;
                int screenWidth = 0;
                Display display = getDisplay();

                display.getSize(size);
                screenWidth = size.x - (350 + 30); // margin + padding
                screenHeight = size.y;

                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();

                lp.width = screenWidth;
                lp.height = (int) (((float) videoHeight / (float) videoWidth) * (float) screenWidth);
                mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);

                if (mMediaPlayer != null && IsMediaPlayerReady) {
                    if (position > 0)
                        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    findViewById(R.id.media_browser_hoverRootFrameLayout).setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer is created");
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        Log.d(TAG, "HoverSurface changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "HoverSurface destroyed");
        try {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                mMediaPlayer.release();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onHover(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        try {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_HOVER_ENTER");
                show(); // checks the timing
            } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_HOVER_EXIT");
                dismiss();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() + Utils.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the time that detecting hovering.
     *
     * @param ms The time, milliseconds
     */
    public void setHoverDetectTime(int ms) {
        mHoverDetectTimeMS = ms;
    }

    public void dismiss() {
        dismissPopup();
    }

    private void dismissPopup() {
        // remove pending message and dismiss popup
        getMyHandler().removeMessages(MSG_SHOW_POPUP);
        getMyHandler().removeMessages(MSG_DISMISS_POPUP);

        try {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                mMediaPlayer.release();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (getParent() != null)
            ((ViewGroup) getParent()).removeView(this);
    }

    private Handler getMyHandler() {
        if (mHandler == null)
            mHandler = new HoverPopupHandler();
        return mHandler;
    }

    public void show() {
        // send message to show.
        if (getMyHandler().hasMessages(MSG_SHOW_POPUP)) {
            return;
            // getHandler().removeMessages(MSG_SHOW_POPUP);
        }
        getMyHandler().sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_SHOW_POPUP, mHoverDetectTimeMS);
    }

    private void showPopup() {
        if (getParent() == null) {
            final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
            params.x = 350;

            window.addContentView(this, params);
        }

        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        if (mHolder != null) {
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
        }
    }

    ;

    private class HoverPopupHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

//            if (DEBUG)
//                android.util.Log.e(TAG, "handleMessage : " + ((msg.what == MSG_SHOW_POPUP) ? "SHOW" : "DISMISS"));

            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_SHOW_POPUP:
                    showPopup();
                    sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_DISMISS_POPUP, POPUP_TIMEOUT_MS);
                    break;
                case MSG_DISMISS_POPUP:
                    dismissPopup();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```